# How to create a join table using sequelize and sqlite?

Tags: join, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am trying to establish a many-to-many relationship between tables in sqlite using sequelize.
I want to add records to a join table (assign tasks to a user) and retrieve data from that table. For some reason, this does not work. Here is my code:

```
var orm = new Sequelize('db_name', '', '', {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: path.join(__dirname, 'db_name')
});

var User = orm.define('User', {
  username: {type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true}
});

var Task = orm.define('Task', {
 id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true},
 taskName: Sequelize.STRING
});

Task.hasMany(User);
User.hasMany(Task);

Task.sync();
User.sync();
```

Having read documentation (http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/associations/#hasmanytarget-options), I expect that a join table TasksUsers should be created. I also expect .addTask method do be available. Then in another file I have:

```
db.User.findOrCreate({where:{username: "fakeUser"}}); //this seems to work
//some code to populate "Tasks" table;

db.User.find({where: {username: "fakeUser"}}).
  complete(function(err,user){
    console.log("user", user); //the user is found
    db.Task.find({where: {id: "some_value"}}).
      complete(function(err, task) {
        console.log("task", task); //the task is found, so it works up to this point
        user.addTask(task). //this line does not work
          complete(function(err, results){
            console.log("posting error", err);
          });    
      })
  });
```

I get an error "Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: TasksUsers". The user.getTasks() method (without any arguments in the parentheses) does not work for the same reason.

Another observation: for testing purposes, I added these lines of code after establishing hasMany relationships:

```
orm.query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'").success(function (res) {
    console.log("tables", res);
  })
```

The result that I get is tables [ 'Tasks', 'Users' ]

The versions: sequelize 2.0.0-rc2, sqlite3 3.0.4. I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: You need to call `sequelize.sync` in order for the join table to be created. Right now the join table exists in sequelize, but you are only telling sequelize to create the user and task tables, not the TasksUsers table

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me. I should have read documentation more carefully.